# InnerHTML dissapearing on setInterval Function

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have written a simple script and it's job is to change a `innerHTML` of a random element in one section of the page. Somehow when I call the function, and set it to fire every 1 second, when `innerHTML` of a specific element is changed, it doesn't stay that way , it just clears itself and moves on to another element. Can anyone help me with this. Here is the code, thanks in advance.

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById("one");
    var box2 = document.getElementById("two");
    var box3 = document.getElementById("three");
    var box4 = document.getElementById("four");
    var box5 = document.getElementById("five");
    var box6 = document.getElementById("six");
    var box7 = document.getElementById("seven");
    var box8 = document.getElementById("eight");

    var headingArray = ["RAVE", "RUN", "PAINT"];
    var iconArray = ["ion-usb", "ion-android-walk", "ion-android-color-palette"];
    var paragraphArray = ["Wanna good time? <br> Check out nearest party centres","Check out running tracks", "Ckeck out painting places"];

    var boxArray = [box1,box2,box3,box4,box5,box6,box7,box8];
    var heading = document.createElement("h2");
    var icon = document.createElement("i");
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

    function getRandomNumberForContent() {
        var randomHeading = Math.round(Math.random()*2) + 0;
        return randomHeading;
    }
    function getRandomNumberForBox() {
        var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*7) + 0;
        return randomNumber;
    }

    function changeBox() {
        var random = getRandomNumberForContent();
        heading.innerHTML = headingArray[random];
        icon.className = "icon "+iconArray[random]+" big";
        paragraph.innerHTML = paragraphArray[random];

        var randomNum = getRandomNumberForBox();
        boxArray[randomNum].innerHTML = "";
        boxArray[randomNum].appendChild(heading);
        boxArray[randomNum].appendChild(icon);
        boxArray[randomNum].appendChild(paragraph);
    }

    setInterval(changeBox,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhat moving the element to the new div each time the function is called, because you are assigning as a child the same element, not a copy of it.

**You should create the new element inside the changeBox function.**

That's the answer. If you create it outside the function, they will be a unique element that you are assigning either to one div or another.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it moves to another element because you append the same elements somewhere else. You could clone the elements when you append them:

```
boxArray[randomNum].appendChild(heading.cloneNode(true));
boxArray[randomNum].appendChild(icon.cloneNode(true));
boxArray[randomNum].appendChild(paragraph.cloneNode(true));
```